# Kotlin equivalent of Optional.map and a method reference

Tags: kotlin

### The Java

Consider the following Java:

```
private void example() {
  Optional<String> foo = ...
  Optional<String> bar = 
      foo.map(this::transform1)
          .map(this::transform2)
}

private String transform1(String s) {
  return s + "!";
}

private String transform2(String s) {
  return "@" + s;
}
```

Note that the `transform` methods accept non-Optional values.

### Question

*Does Kotlin have a built-in mechanism to achieve the same thing when using its nullable/non-nullabe types?*

### The first attempt

I managed to achieve this effect with the following:

```
fun <A, B> nullMap(a: A?, mapper: (a: A) -> B?): B? =
  if (a != null) mapper.invoke(a) else null

fun example() {
  val foo: String? = "Space cookies"
  val bar1: String? = nullMap(foo, Example::transform1)
  val bar2: String? = nullMap(bar1, Example::transform2)
}

fun transform(s: String) = s + "!"
fun transform2(s: String) = "@" + s
```

(Again, we note that for the `transform` methods, `s` is a non-nullable String.)

So, my question stated another way is: Does a `nullMap` equivalent already exist in Kotlin's standard library? And/or: is there a different standard way of doing this?

Finally, can the visually cleaner *chaining* approach be achieved in Kotlin, rather than either separate assignments (above) or nested function calls?  For a moment I considered that you could add `nullMap` as an extension method on `Any`, but sometimes the receiver you're trying to invoke a method on is `null` (so that won't work).

Comment: It should be pointed out that the assertion `sometimes the receiver you're trying to invoke a method on is null (so that won't work).` is not true - you *can* have an extension function on a nullable type and it's no problem that the receiver is null.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We use [safe call operator](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls):

```
val foo: Foo? = ...
foo?.toA()?.toB()
```

Or

```
foo?.let(this::transform1)?.let(this::transform2)
```

Kotlin emphasis on null safety. There is [an entire chapter](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) in its manual describing related technics.

Comment: It's `let` that I'm looking for thanks.  I'm aware of the null-safe operators.

Comment: Kotlin has a bunch of such functions, like `let`, `apply`, `run`, `also`, `use`, `with`. Just mentioning them so you won't be lost searching for another of them.

Comment: Thanks @glee8e - I will have to spend some time just reading the [standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/index.html)